# how to assign functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I just discovered the property keyword for defining functions for objects. I tried to refactor my websocket experiment using objects, but I can't get it to work.

This works (no objects):

```
var ws = new WebSocket(something, somethingelse);
ws.onopen = function() {
   ws.send("hello");
   console.log("works");
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
function MyObject() {
   this.ws = new WebSocket(something, somethingelse);
   this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
}

MyObject.prototype.onOpen = function() {
    this.ws.send("hello");   // undefined!
};
```

Why is ws undefined? Am I assigning the onOpen function incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using the `new` keyword? There's a bunch of stuff wrong here; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What "property keyword?"

Comment: onOpen function will be called by WebSocket object, and "this" will be actually WebSocket object but not the MyObject. (*If I'm not messing things arround..*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning functions correctly (there is only one way of assigning functions), your problem is that the context of the function changes.

Consider this line:

```
this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
```

**Possibility 1:**

Now I assume, *inside* `WebSocket`, somewhere this function gets called as a response to an opening connection (like an event handler), probably like

```
this.onopen();
```

[What `this` refers to inside a function is determined by **how** a function is called on run time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (`<-` read this link, it helps a lot). It is not bound at definition time. In your case, `this` would refer to the `WebSocket` instance.

So inside if called this way, inside `MyObject.prototype.onOpen`, `this` refers to `this.ws`, the `WebSocket` instance, which does not have a `ws` property, and not the `MyObject` instance.

This can be solved in two ways:

1. Since `this` already refers to `this.ws`, you can call `send` directly on `this`:

   ```
   MyObject.prototype.onOpen = function() {
       this.send("hello");
   };
   ```
2. If you want `this` inside `MyObject.prototype.onOpen` to always refer to the `MyObject` instance, you have to keep an explicit reference to the instance, e.g. through a closure:

   ```
   var self = this;
   this.ws.onopen = function() {
       self.onOpen();
   };
   ```

   Now inside `onOpen`, `this` refers to the `MyObject` instance which has a property `ws`, just like you set it up in the constructor.

   In browsers supporting ECMAScript 5, functions already have a method for this technique, called `.bind()`:

   ```
   this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen.bind(this);
   ```

---

**Possibility 2:**

It could also be that `WebSocket` calls `onopen` in such a way:

```
this.onopen.call(null);
```

In that case, `this` would either refer to `window` or would be `undefined`, depending on whether the code runs in strict mode or not (it does not matter, in any case it is a problem).

This situation could only be solved with the second solution from the first possibility.

---

**Why does the first example work?**

```
var ws = new WebSocket(something, somethingelse);
ws.onopen = function() {
   ws.send("hello");
   console.log("works");
}
```

In this case, the function you assign to `ws.onopen` is a closure, closing over the variables defined in this scope, also `ws`. In this sense it is similar to the second way of solving the problem, but

```
ws.onopen = function() {
   this.send("hello");
   console.log("works");
}
```

would probably work as well.

Comment: Yea, I did something exactly similar to this when I was working with WebSockets.

Comment: Ah, one of the most misunderstood JavaScript "feature". The `this` keyword.